# Why is there no space between bash text output and next prompt and how to fix it?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal

This is not the first or only time I face this "issue", but this time I thought to go after an explanation. When retrieving some dummy value from a local machine, there is the corresponding output and *immediately after* the next prompt starts, no new line and not even a single space in between. I know I did not include a carriage return or a new line command in the output string, but is it wrong of me to assume that bash "resets" to a clean, new line after a complete and successful command?

```sh
R2D2-Air:~ kopaka$ 
R2D2-Air:~ kopaka$ 
R2D2-Air:~ kopaka$ curl localhost:8080
asdfR2D2-Air:~ kopaka$ 
R2D2-Air:~ kopaka$
```

Why does the the terminal behave like this? Is this working as designed and thus, are my expectations wrong? Or is this the result of some erroneous usage I'm not aware of?

Comment: If the output of a command doesn't contain a newline and the shell doesn't add a newline before the prompt, there will be no line break. Some shells may do other things to indicate that the output doesn't have a trailing newline. Try `printf "abc\n"` and `printf "abc"`.

Comment: I'd say that you can't assume bash appending a new line after a successful command. Files and messages should end with their new line if needed. However, you can configure your terminal to prompt to a new line if the previous command did not. Check this for further information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60459/how-to-make-bash-put-prompt-on-a-new-line-after-cat-command

Comment: I get how it works, but I still can't grasp, how my assumption is *that* far-fetched. Thanks for the link though, it's dealing with the exact question I was bearing in mind.